# Cannot convert Value type MPOFace Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I am currently working on a tutorial for Face recognition using MS cognitive services.

I get to this point in the tutorial (who uses Swift 2 and Xcode 7) but it throws up this error that says:

> Cannot convert value type[MPOFace]!, err:NSError!) to expected argument type MPOFace completionBlock.

Does anyone have any answer to this and if so a little explanation I am new to this and like to learn as much as I can.

```
func downloadFaceId() {
    if let image = personimage, let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) {
        FaceService.instance.client.detect(with: imageData, returnFaceId: true, returnFaceLandmarks: false, returnFaceAttributes: nil, completionBlock: { (face:[MPOFace]!, err:NSError!) in
            if err == nil {
                var faceId: String?
                for face in faces {
                    faceId = face.faceId
                    break
                }

                self.faceId = faceId
            }
         })
```

Comment: try remove both !s

Comment: Hi Thank you for you response 季亨达, I still get the same error without them.

Comment: Can you show me the type of completionBlock?

Comment: Not Sure what that will be, I am new to programming. The error says. cannot convert to MPOFaceArray Completion Block! if that is any help

Comment: Just type FaceService.instance.client.detect(with: ....) and not fulfill them, you will see the types, and copy the type of completionBlock to me

Comment: Ok, Now I understand.  this is the block I chose from the tutorial....... FaceService.instance.client?.detect(with: Data!, returnFaceId: Bool, returnFaceLandmarks: Bool, returnFaceAttributes: [Any]!, completionBlock: MPOFaceArrayCompletionBlock!MPOFaceArrayCompletionBlock!([MPOFace]?, Error?) -> Void)

Comment: So try to replace both !s to ?s

Comment: I gat the same error but if I replace NSError to Error then it works with the ?'s but i do get a Yellow Triangle Error saying Expression of URLSessionDataTask? Unused but the program runs.

Comment: let _ = FaceService.instance.client?.detect.   It is a kind of old API. The new Xcode feedbacks a warning for the instance that is not used.

Comment: Ok Thank you for your time on this 季亨达, I do appreciate it.

Comment: My pleasure ! :):):):)